# HAVI undefined error when creating AVI files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, avi, vfw

I'm trying to create an AVI file from a series of BMP images and am using Lucian Wischik's source code from http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/avi_utils.html however when I

```
#include "avi_utils.h"
```

I get a bunch of errors when compiling that include things like HAVI: undeclared identifier.  Has anyone worked with this code before and know what I am doing wrong?

I'm using Visual Studios 2010 and creating it as a Win32 console visual c++ application and I have a link to the vfw32.lib external library in preferences already.

Thanks

Comment: have you put #define STRICT and #include <windows.h> before avi_utils

Comment: thanks that fixed it it seems, now it's giving me a syntax error for identifier 'AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS' which seems to be declared in vfw, not sure if I'm getting the error because of the order of my #includes or not

Comment: you may update your question tilte or post a new one but just an advice , put more code in your question because, with 1 line... it's more a riddle than a technical question!